# Как установить кодировку для консоли в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

В WinAPI есть функция   `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)` которая меняет кодировку консоли. Есть ли аналог данной функции в Qt ?

Comment: Кодирование символов

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html, но прямого аналога нет

Comment: учитывая, что эта проблема почти всегда только в винде и повторяется, можно аккуратно завернуть SetConsoleOutputCP в дефайн и забыть.